# Form: make a loop to save different value of a same field name

Tags: php, forms, loops

I do a form, inside I would like to do a loop for to show the same field. Each field will have different value and I would like to use sessions to take all the value.

Here is my code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { //normally not 5 but a random number, choose by user
     echo "Numero ";
     echo $i;
?>      
<input type="text" name="number2" id="number2"/>    
<?php
}
?>
</form>
<?php
echo $_POST['number2'];
$my_array=array($_POST['number2']);
    $_SESSION['countnumb']=$my_array;
```

in another page:

```
foreach($_SESSION['countnumb'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
}
```

I can't register any number. How can I do this? thanks

Comment: the pages need to have `session_start()`

Answer (score 1):

Basics First - `ids` should be unique in a webpage.

Declaring `<input type="text" name="number2" id="number2"/>` in a loop is **wrong**.

For creating multiple input using loop try like this-

```
echo "<input type='text' name='number[$i]' id='number{$i}' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="number[2]" id="number2"/>
```

would make `$_POST['number']` an array which you can loop though server side, This is described here http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

```
foreach ($_POST['number'] as $number){
echo $number;
}
```

for example

this would make your code

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { //normally not 5 but a random number, choose by user
     echo "<input type="text" name="number[$i]" id="number{$i}"/>  ";
?>      

<?php
}
?>
</form>
<?php
print_r( $_POST['number']  );

$_SESSION['countnumb']= $_POST['number'];
```

Comment: if you put `[2]` how will it make an array?

Comment: the [2] specifically doesnt matter, it was just his example.

Comment: If you don't describe about what [2] does i dont think the answer helps much. what if op puts `<input type="text" name="number[2]" id="number2"/> <input type="text" name="number[2]" id="number2"/>  <input type="text" name="number[2]" id="number2"/>` it won't work then